# layouts with different dpi do not work well

Tags: android, layout, dpi

in my App I have 2 different layouts for the same layout.

1. normal
2. sw420dp

both are the same with just minor fixes for bigger dpi screen however when i launch the emulator with the nexus 5 1920x1080 420 dpi it shows me the "normal" layout rather then the -sw420dp one , have i wrote it incorrectly cause i double checked and everything seems to be in order however it dose not work well...

please help.

[image: example]

Comment: 420dpi... do you mean 480 dpi?

Comment: the emulator is created 1920x1080:420dpi, but I think the android resources  directory should be 480dp?

Answer (score 0):

The `-swXXXdp` resource directory suffix stands for "smallest width: XXX dp". It is meant to be used to differentiate between different screen *sizes*, not different screen *densities*.

From the [Android developer guides](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms):

> `px = dp * (dpi / 160)`

So for you, `1080 = dp * (420 / 160)`, or `dp = 411.42`.

Since 411.42 is less than 420, your phone will display the "normal" layout.